# Android Studio Gradle sync issue: Unable to resolve plugin artifact

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

I'm encountering a Gradle sync error after adding a module to my Android Studio project. Removing the module and its SDK didn't resolve the issue.

Error:

```
Build file '/home/ishan/AndroidStudioProjects/StaffScanDemo/build.gradle.kts' line: 7

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

Exception is: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.1.2')
```

build.gradle.kts (Project Level)

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0")
    }
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false

}
```

setting.gradle.kts

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "StaffScanDemo"
include(":app")
```

I attempted various solutions suggested in similar Stack Overflow questions, including adding the android-library plugin to the project's build.gradle file.

Removed the problematic module and its SDK from the project structure, but the error persists. But if I try to add a new module then it says a module with that name already exists.

I'm seeking assistance in identifying the root cause of this error and implementing an effective solution. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typo? It settings.gradle.kts